# update Date() function result immediately after machine time change

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript's `Date()` object for various things in my program. However, I noticed that whenever the clock on the machine changes, the time returned by `Date()` is still equal to the time before the change up until a minute after the change and only then it takes effect.

So is the time was `23:50:39` and I manually changed the time on the machine to `23:59:50` and refreshed the page I would still see: `23:50:51` (the time has progressed a-bit) and not the desired time.

Is there any way to force javascript to pull the new machine time every time I do `new Date()`?

Comment: In which browsers do you see this?

Comment: @Niko Google Chrome. Haven't tested it on any other browser since I have to make it work on Google Chrome

Answer (score 2):

It seems that V8 keeps an internal cache of various values used for date / time computation read at startup (source code [here](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/date.js) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/date.h)). This is in order to avoid expensive system calls every time it needs to build a JS Date object.

Maybe for some reasons, V8 is failing to catch the notification of date/time change that resets those cached values.

Comment: Just as i suspected. I guess there is currently not a way to force it to retrieve the machine time.

Comment: Which OS? Which Chrome version? How do you change the system date? On my system (Linux+Chromium38) setting the date from command line with `date` works fine.

Comment: Windows 7 chrome v38. Changing the clock manually. (you can get to that clock change dialog by typing `timedate.cpl` in cmd)

Comment: What if you change the date from cmd using `time` or `date`?

Comment: Haven't checked that because there are reasons why it has to be done through window's dialog ;/

Comment: Anyway, it could be interesting to test your app with different browsers ans OS, for the sake of curiosity, even if you need to make it work only on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this also. After clearing browser data (CTRL-SHIFT-DEL, check only images and files) the date will reflect the new system date, so it looks like Chrome uses an internal date/time value derived from the system date at browser startup.

I'm not aware of a way to programmatically clear the browser cache, other [than this experimental API](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/clear).